# How to create a bean for JPA Respository extened interface ( working in multiple modules)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I was using 2 modules:

1. common module
2. User module

In common module I used an interface that extends JPA Respository (Ex : commonRepository) for access of data.
When I just running the common module it works fine as Expected

I just add the dependency of the common module in user module in POM.XML

In controller I calling a service method of common module where the commonRepository is autowired in the commonService

Code for Common Module :

```
CommonController -> CommonServiceInterface -> CommonServiceImplementation (Autowired of CommonRepository) -> CommonRepository extends JPARespository -> getData()
```

Code for User Module:

```
UserController (Autowired of CommonServiceInterface )-> Access the getData() from CommonRespository
```

Error:

```
Field commonRepository in com.common.commonServiceImplementationrequired a bean of type 'com.common.repository.CommonRepository' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Note:
If I access directly the CommonRepository Interface from UserController it works fine:

```
UserController (Autowired of CommonRepository)-> Access the getData() from CommonRespository
```

when I am accessing via service layer like below it throws the above error

```
UserController (Autowired of CommonServiceInterface )-> Access the getData() from CommonRespository
```

Source code available in

https://github.com/navee-kumar/CommonRepository

https://github.com/navee-kumar/DependentRepository

Answer (score 0):

Adding Autowired in your serviceImpl is need.

```
@Autowired
private CountryRepository countryRepository;

public SimpleMasterServiceImpl(CountryRepository countryRepository) {
    this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
}

@Override
public String getData() {
    return countryRepository.findAllByOrderByCountryName().get(0).getCountryName();
}

@Override
public String demoCheck() {
    return "demoCheck....";
}
```

Comment: But I had already added in configuration file
File Name : MasterConfig.java

And I imported that config file in Dependent Configuration File
File Name : DependentConfig.java